# How to handle potential race conditions between codepush and Google playstore / Apple appstore

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I just built my first React Native app and am very excited about the ability to send OTA updates via codepush. However, what does the release process look like when I have made changes.
Imagine the following happens:

```
v1 -> released to playstore
v2 -> bugfix: released via codepush
v3 -> native changes: released to playstore
```

A user that downloads v3 from google playstore, upon app open, will he get v2 from codepush ? I can't push v3 to codepush because it has native changes that might break.

Weird that none of the codepush articles / documentation covers this potential race condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the below text from the codepush documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/tree/master/cli#target-binary-version-parameter)

> **Target binary version parameter**
>
> This specifies the store/binary version of the application you are
>   releasing the update for, so that only users running that version will
>   receive the update, while users running an older and/or newer version
>   of the app binary will not. This is useful for the following
>   reasons:
>
> 1) If a user is running an older binary version, it's possible
>   that there are breaking changes in the CodePush update that wouldn't
>   be compatible with what they're running.
>
> 2) If a user is running a newer
>   binary version, then it's presumed that what they are running is newer
>   (and potentially incompatible) with the CodePush update. If you don't
>   specify the targetBinaryVersion in the release command, it takes from
>   the build.gradle (or) If you specify the target version, the current
>   release would be mapped to it.

Assuming you have a new release which would be sent to users via play store, it is inferred that the version code and build number would be updated and the earlier code-push release will no longer point to this build.

So to answer your questions.

**A user that downloads v3 from google playstore, upon app open, will he get v2 from codepush ?**

No they wouldn't get it as the code push release would be mapped to earlier binary version

**I can't push v3 to codepush because it has native changes that might break.**

You can with changes made over v3 which is already there in market

Comment: Thanks @Karthik Pala, this is exactly what I needed. Will give it a try

Comment: accepted. yes, specifying the target binary version worked !

Comment: running into a different issue now. Any ideas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685589/codepush-updates-appversion-is-incorrect-its-always-the-same-as-the-current-a